# How to toggle draggable with Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-directive

I added the JQuery draggable to the page using Angular JS directive.  The code looks like this:

HTML

```
...
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows"
        directive-draggable
        directive-droppable>
        <td>{{row.data1}}</td>
        <td>{{row.data2}}</td>
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" ng-click="toggleEditMode()">EDIT</button>
```

Angular JS Controller

```
...
$scope.editMode = false;
...
$scope.toggleEditMode = function() {
    $scope.editMode = !$scope.editMode;
}
```

Angular JS Directive (Draggable)

```
return {
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $element.draggable({
            ...logic...
        });
    }
}
```

What I want to do is once I hit the edit button, I want to enable `draggable` (when `$scope.editMode == true`).  I tried this in the directive, but it's not working.

```
if($scope.$parent.$parent.editMode) {
    $element.draggable({
        ...
    })
}
```

How can I do this? Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never want to access options the way you are doing. What you will want to do is tie your scope's directive from something in your Controller's scope.

Basically you want to watch for changes to a property that exists on the caller's scope. You will want to create an isolate scope on your directive (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive).

Example: (http://jsfiddle.net/TwoToneBytes/5jVUM/1). Here's the important part:

```
    scope: {
        enabled: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        var $elem = $(elem);
        $elem.draggable();

        scope.$watch('enabled', function (val) {
            $elem.draggable(val === true ? 'enable' : 'disable');
        });
    }
```